# In my python email script running in bash, after attempting to run it it gives me this "'email' is not a package" error. Any ideas?

Tags: python, bash, email

I found this email sending python script to use in bash and I can not find help related to this anywhere, so this is the script:

```
FROM = "example"
TO = ["example"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Subject"
TEXT = "Your Text"

# Prepare actual message
message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail
import email
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp.example.com)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

my goal is to have this script run in bash and send the email to the recipient. 
the error i get when running this after replacing "example" with accurate emails is this:

`ImportError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package`

EDIT:
here is what is outputted:

```
    """ % (FROM, ", TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 86, in <module>
    import email
  File "/home/user/email.py", line 15, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package

Original exception was:
  File "mailtest.py", line 21
    """ % (FROM, ", TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: Did you save the script as `email.py`? It's shadowing the `email` package in the standard library.

Comment: @chepner no the script is not named anything near email because of the warnings I read about it, still doesnt work.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is. Your script doesn't try to access a `utils` attribute of `email` (in fact, your script doesn't need to import `email` at all).

Comment: Apart from the missing `email` package, `server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp.example.com)` looks fishy. It should be replaced by a real smtp server and enclosed in quotation marks. This works for me: `server = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")` but I'm actually running a local mailserver.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Your code doesn't import `email.utils` and I'd like to see where it is coming from. Also, can you write a test script that is nothing but those two imports and see if it works? Stylistically one usually puts imports at the top of the file and this can be handy for stopping the script early when import fails.

Comment: Its still likely that you have an `email.py` in your script directory. You could `import email;print(email.__file__)` to see if you got the standard email package or a different script.

Comment: I peeked at `smtplib` and noticed that it does `import email.utils`. This would have been clear in the traceback had you posted it.

Comment: @tdelaney if everything is imported then what do you think is the issue with the script? sorry about the traceback thing btw

Comment: @notaproatbash - I don't think everything's imported. I think that the `import email.utils` done by `smtplib` when you `import smtplib` fails. That means that the `email` module is not the standard `email` module in python's standard lib. `import email;print(email.__file__)` will tell you where the module is located. If you add that little bit of code to the top of your script, you could answer the question. I think you have a script called `email.py` in the same directory as the script you are running. Just a guess, prove me wrong!

Comment: @tdelaney so i have no idea what im looking for but I will put it on the question now.

Comment: @tdelaney the output is now edited onto the main question, not really sure what it means however.

Comment: Notice _File "/home/user/email.py", line 15, in <module>_. You have a script named email.py masking the real python email module. You also have a syntax error that will sitll need to be addressed once you've disposed of /home/user/email.py.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that should duplicate the problem if you put it in the same directory as your current program.

test.py

```
import email
print("email module path:", email.__file__)
import smtplib
```

I tried to duplicate your environment by creating a script called `email.py` in the same directory. When I run `test.py`, I get your error

```
~/tmp$ touch email.py
~/tmp$ python test.py
email module path: /home/td/tmp/email.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/home/td/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package
~/tmp$
```

Notice that the email module path is not python's email package.

Comment: This helped me so much i was too confident thinking that I had nothing named email in my directory but turns out that that was the problem the whole time. however I still get the other error regarding the ```  File "mailtest.py", line 17
    """ % (FROM, ", TO, SUBJECT, TEXT) ``` any idea on this error?

Comment: Yes, in `(FROM, ", TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)` that's a double quote without a closing quote. You want `(FROM, "", TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)`

Comment: it seems to be closing on the triple quote prior to it, even though i put the double quotes. Is this triple quote necessary?

Comment: The triple quotes are needed for the multiline string. The code you posted is `(FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)`. It looks like the middle bit `".join(TO)` has been changed, injecting the error. The original code seems right to me. Sometimes syntax highlighters don't get it right so color change is not necessary diagnostic.